# Cannot access service at external ip Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a problem that I cannot access service with curl althought I have external IP.I meet a timeout request. Here is my services

`NAME                TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)          AGE
crawler-manager-1   NodePort   10.103.18.210   192.168.0.10   3001:30029/TCP   2h
redis               NodePort   10.100.67.138   192.168.0.11   6379:30877/TCP   5h`
and here my yaml service file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\kubernetes-kompose\tools\kompose.exe
      convert -f docker-compose.yml
    kompose.version: 1.17.0 (a74acad)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: crawler-manager-1
  name: crawler-manager-1
  namespace: cbpo-example
spec:
  type: NodePort
  externalIPs:
    - 192.168.0.10
  ports:
  - name: "3001"
    port: 3001
    targetPort: 3001
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: crawler-manager-1
    run: redis
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Here my deployment yml file

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\kubernetes-kompose\tools\kompose.exe
      convert -f docker-compose.yml
    kompose.version: 1.17.0 (a74acad)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: crawler-manager-1
  name: crawler-manager-1
  namespace: cbpo-example
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: crawler-manager-1
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      containers:
      - args:
        - npm
        - start
        env:
        - name: DB_HOST
          value: mysql
        - name: DB_NAME
        - name: DB_PASSWORD
        - name: DB_USER
        - name: REDIS_URL
          value: redis://cbpo-redis
        image: localhost:5000/manager
        name: crawler-manager-1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3001
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

Anyone have a problem like me when work with kubernetes? I need to access to check if 2 service in my namespace can connect each other, Thanks so much.

Comment: How is your cluster deployed? The external IP addresses of those services are inside a [private network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network#Private_IPv4_addresses). So unless your machine is connected to that network you won't be able to access it.

Comment: thanks you for your help, I just deploy in a single node. I just want to test my services can communicate each other, here's my pod I create for my namespace

Comment: `NAME                 STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
docker-for-desktop   Ready     master    10d       v1.10.11`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of communication through ip addresses for your services you can communicate with their DNS names.

> “Normal” (not headless) Services are assigned a DNS A record for a
> name of the form my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local. This resolves
> to the cluster IP of the Service.
>
> “Headless” (without a cluster IP)
> Services are  also assigned a DNS A record for a name of the form
> my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local. Unlike normal Services, this
> resolves to the set of IPs of the pods selected by the Service.
> Clients are expected to consume the set or else use standard
> round-robin selection from the set.

For more info, please check [Kubernetes DNS for Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#services)

Comment: Thanks you so much coolinuxoid, I think you have showed me another way to resolve my problem

Comment: You are welcome, if this was helpful, I kindly ask you to accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you see end points for the app. One reason this can happen is becuase of pod name mismatch.. if i remember, it's `selector.name`

```
 kubectl get endpoints
 NAME         ENDPOINTS            AGE
 kubernetes   192.168.63.13:8080   1d
```